# JavaScript RegExp to match a given string only if it is not surrounded by brackets

Tags: javascript, regex

I am looking for a JavaScript regular expression that would match the word "foo" in a phrase `"This <is foo"` or `"This is foo"` or `"This is foo>"` but would not match in the phrase `"This <is foo>"`. I know that in other languages this is solved by using negative lookbehinds, but AFAIK, JavaScript does not support these. I have come across similar questions, but none of them matched exactly what I am looking for, and I can't think of a solution on my own. I would be grateful for any hint.

I am testing my attempts [here](http://www.regexpal.com/).

Comment: What have you tried at http://www.regexpal.com/? Please share. Are you extracting or replacing text?

Comment: My goal is to replace text

Comment: @EdgarNavasardyan He's asking for you to tell us what you have _already tried_. We understand what you want to do.

Comment: Could you elaborate more on valid vs invalid strings? Your question title says you want to match strings that aren't surrounded by brackets, but the invalid string you posted *contains* brackets (not fully surrounded by them). Should the regex match `This ` in that last example? Because that part isn't surrounded by brackets. It looks like you're just trying to avoid any string that contains `<` and `>` at any point, in that order. Is this correct?

Comment: The question is: does yours? What is not working? What is the problem with?

Comment: I am sorry. The regular expression should match a target string ("foo" in my example) only and only if it is NOT between an opening and closing brackets)

Answer (score 2):

You can match it as group not bounded by the opening and closing brackets.

```
[^<].*(foo).*[^>]
```

Comment: I meant that I need a sort of lookbegind/lookahead. That is, I need only `foo` to be included in the result